# Unable to start minikube

Tags: minikube

I am runing the following command

```
/usr/bin/minikube start --vm-driver none
```

I get the following error

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
E0101 22:32:32.684493  122952 start.go:223] Error updating cluster:  error creating file at /usr/local/bin/localkube: open /usr/local/bin/localkube: read-only file system
```

How an I workaround this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and fixed it
please try below command:

```
brew install docker-machine-driver-xhyve
```